# Issues Making Android App Movable To SD Card

Tags: android

From everything I have read, all that is needed to make an app movable to SD is adding the following line to the manifest:

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

I tried adding this to both of my company's apps, and while the move option appeared in the settings for both, only one could actually be moved successfully. When the move button is pressed for the other app, it attempts the move, then pops up a "cannot move" message. I was able to track down the actual text of the error, but it is not much help: "MOVE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR"

I thought it might be because the failing app has c code embedded into it. As a test I attempted to move the default "hello world" app that Android Studio creates for both a regular Android app and one with built in c++ support. Neither was able to successfully move.

I have tried to move all of these apps on a couple of different devices, and all had the same result.

Does anyone know what might cause some apps to be movable, while others are not, even when they all have the appropriate directive to allow them to move applied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to side load the APK, not install it via the USB from Android Studio.